# Integration Spock Testing Framework into Eclipse Neon2 v4.6.2

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, junit4, spock

I'm using Eclipse Neon2 (4.6.2). I'm trying to use Spock Framework (http://spockframework.org/). Here's what I did so far:

1. Added the Groovy plugin to Eclipse. Since in the Eclipse Market there's no Groovy plug-in for this specific version of Eclipse (Neon2 V4.6.2), i followed the instructions mentioned here and specifically in the 'How To Install' section: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki
2. I right clicked on my Eclipse Project and converted it to a Groovy project.
3. I installed Spock Plugin 2.13 by Jspresso from the Eclipse Marketplace.
4. I right-clicked on my Eclipse project and added the 'Spock Nature' to it.

At this stage I'm able to create Groovy classes but the IDE still cannot identify Spock syntax. For example when extending Spock's Specification class, we get a class not found or package not found error.

I realize how this can be much easier using Maven or Gradle, but that's a long story now and I'm just trying to find out what i'm doing wrong so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add Spock as a dependency of your project? It needs to be on the classpath when compiling your tests.

Comment: I thought about that, but then what's the point of 'Adding Spock Nature' to your project. What is that doing exactly? But anyway, when all things failed i tried to add the spock jar to my build path and this is the jar file i found when attempting to add an external jar: org.jspresso.contrib.sjsplugin.spock_3.0.7.201611272038.jar. I added it, but still the main Spock 'Specification' class could not be found.

Comment: From the documentation, here's what the Spock plugin does: Here are the feature included :

Syntax highlighting
Keywords completion
Junit tracing pane's font replacement by a monospace font (for better readability of groovy formated assertions)

Comment: You added the Eclipse Spock Plugin jar; you need to add the Spock jar.